# Можно ли создать свой локальный закрытый git репозиторий?

Tags: git, github

Можно ли создать свой локальный закрытый git репозиторий? Систему без пуша на удаленный сервер github, для команды.

Comment: Любой локальный репозиторий на вашем компьютере по определению является закрытым, пока вы его не опубликуете где нибудь. На гитхабе — за денежку.

Comment: Поддерживаю @andreymal если нужны приватные репозитории за даром посмотрите на gitlab

Comment: ну, можно в расшаренной папке создать..

Comment: @Igor Ognichenko, еще халавные закрытые репозитории на битбакете можно создавать

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Репозитории в git не разделяются на открытые и закрытые.

Git — *распределённая* система контроля версий. Каждый репозиторий самодостаточен, не опирается ни на какое внешнее хранилище, сетевое или иное.

Взаимодействуя с GitHub, вы на самом деле работаете не с одним, а с **двумя отдельными самостоятельными репозиториями**: локальным и удалённым, размещёнными у вас на компьютере и на серверах GitHub соответственно.

Непосредственно изменениями занимаетесь в локальном. Он находится у вас на диске и с сетью никак сам по себе не связан. Просто папка с файлами. Удалённый же нужен лишь для переноса уже сформированных коммитов куда-нибудь ещё: публиковать в интернете, переносить на флэшку (`git push` можно сделать на флэшку, да) и т. п.

Если удалённый расположен на GitHub, то уже он может быть открытым или закрытым, но это особенность именно GitHub, не git.